# C# - EF CodeFirst - HasOptional properties create new objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have next model with mapping:

```
public partial class BPart
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Part PartNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Revision Revision { get; set; }        
    public Assembly Assembly { get; set; }        
    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    public double Qty { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public OrderState OrderState { get; set; }        
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    public bool IsRemoved { get; set; }
    public BPart()
    {
        Id = Guid.Empty;
        Assembly = new Assembly();
        Vendor = new Vendor();
        OrderState = new OrderState();
    }
}

public BOMPartMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Qty);
        this.Property(t => t.Unit)
             .HasMaxLength(100);                      
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("BOMPart");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); ;
        this.Property(t => t.Qty).HasColumnName("Qty");
        this.Property(t => t.Unit).HasColumnName("Unit");
        this.Property(t => t.IsRemoved).HasColumnName("IsRemoved");
        this.Property(t => t.AdditionalInformation).HasColumnName("AdditionalInformation");
        this.HasRequired(t=>t.PartNumber)
            .WithMany(t=>t.BOMS)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("PartReferenceId"));
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Revision)
            .WithMany(t => t.Parts)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("RevisionReferenceId"));
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Assembly)
            .WithMany(t => t.Parts)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("AssemblyReferenceId"));
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Vendor)
            .WithMany(t => t.OrderedParts)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("VendorReferenceId"));
        this.HasOptional(t => t.OrderState)
            .WithMany(t => t.Parts)
            .Map(c => c.MapKey("OrderStateReferenceId"));
    }
}
```

When I created new BOMPart object with NULLable OrderState and Vendor, EF created Optional objects(Vendor and OrderState) as well. My object before saving looks like:

```
BPart.Vendor = null
BPart.OrderState = null
```

I checked data base and there this optional fields has check mart NULLABLE. But I can not figure out why EF creates new object for optional fields.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: optional navigation properties on one-to-many relationships require nullable FK's in your table to reference them, if that's what you're asking. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: Updated question in topic. I created: BPart with Vendor - null and OrderState - null. But EF created new entities for Vendor and OrderState togerher for BPart as well.

Comment: are you sure the vendor and orderstate made in constructor were not part of the context as well? Or even in the database, if there is no FK constraint.

Comment: How I can check that it's part of context? For some reason Id for Vendor and OrderState were generated. For Vendor and Order state I have next option in mapping files: 
   ` this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id")
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);`  Could it be a problem?

Comment: No, it's not a problem. New Vendor and OrderState were created with next Guid Id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: Fixed! As you said, just because my mapper contain Vendor and OrderState my BPart was created with Vendor and OrderState, so context was creating default objects. I separated BPart on 2 object. Into inherited one I added OrderState and Vendor, modified Map file and created additional Map file for extended BPart object.